# Samba - Password protected share

Tags: server, permissions, password

I've configured a SAMBA server with 2 shares, one is public and the other is private, which is password protected.

The server works brilliantly, I can access both shared folders, and the password protected one asks for login (user and password), which is fine.

My issue is, is I login to the password protected folder the it stays accessible to everyone on the same windows machine.

Is there any thing I could do, so that I could lock the private folder before I leave the machine? or is it possible to add a timeout so that the folder would be locked after e.g. 8 hours?

We are a small company and the laptops are there to be used by several people, so it would be fantastic if I could lock the password protected folder after I finished with the laptop.

We use Ubuntu 18.04 and about all our machines are windows 10 machines.

our samba config is as follows:

#======================= Global Settings #=====================================

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = PRIMARY %v 
netbios name = PRIMARY
disable netbios = Yes
security = user
map to guest = bad user 
dns proxy = no
```

#-----------------secure-passowrd----------

```
[DATA]
path = /media/DATA
valid users = @technical
guest ok = no
writable = yes
browsable = yes
```

Many thanks

M

Comment: Please format the pasted text as `code` using the { } icon above the edit question window.

Comment: Have you tried matching samba username and password with the Windows username and password? For example, create an user `technical` with the same password as the samba password in Windows. Then log into Windows as the `technical` user, and access the restricted samba share from there. Then log out from Windows as technical` when you are done using the restricted samba share.

Comment: This seems more like a Windows client security problem than an Ubuntu samba server problem.

Comment: Many thanks for all your help, I will try to match windows password with the samba password and report back.  thanks again

Comment: Match both user name and password. Then Windows should not ask for samba password when you open the share. When you log out the samba share should close.